# How to get value from text box by name which is dynamic

Tags: javascript

I need a value of `text box` for that I am using `document.getElementsByName("elemntName")` but the problem is the the `name` itself is dynamic, something like below.

```
for(temp = 0 ; temp < arracid.length ; temp++){
    cell1=mynewrow.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML="<input type='hidden' name='ACID"+index+"' class='tblrows'  id='ACID"+index+"' value='"+arracid[temp]+"'>";
    index++;
 }
```

When I tried `var acidCount = document.getElementsByName('ACID')` its not working and I tried

`var acidCount = document.getElementsByName('ACID"+index+"')` still not working

For every loop the name is changing like `ACID1`,`ACID2` etc.. can anyone help me how to get the `value` of this text box?

Comment: When do you want to read the value of text box? When user types?\

Comment: it is hidden the inputs

Answer (score 2):

(This is a jquery solution, since the question was initially tagged with jQuery)

You can use the selector of input elements with name starting with `^=` ACID:

```
$("input[name^=ACID]").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Yeah earlier it was.

Comment: @KAD I have total three text boxes like `ACID,RCID,NWID` so, for every text box do I need to use loop, becomes total 3 loops?

Comment: You can combine the selectors if you want to treat them all the same way: `$("input[name^=ACID], input[name^=RCID], input[name^=NWID]")`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already assigning an ID to your inputs, it's recommended to use `getElementsById` which is faster than `getElementsByName` (and more accurate because the IDs are supposed to be unique, while the names don't have to be). Try this:

```
var acidCount = document.getElementById("ACID" + index);
```

If you still want to use `getElementsByName`, try this:

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID" + index);
```

But remember that `getElementsByName` returns a list of elements, but the list has only one element, because your names are unique. If you want to get that element in the list, you can use it's index like this:

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID" + index)[0];
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the list of all your inputs, first remove the index from the name:

```
cell1.innerHTML="<input type='hidden' name='ACID' class='tblrows'  id='ACID"+index+"' value='"+arracid[temp]+"'>";
```

Then use:

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID");
```

Note: all the above return the DOM element(s). If you're only interested in the value, use the `value` property:

```
var acidCount = document.getElementById("ACID" + index).value;
```

or

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID" + index)[0].value;
```

Comment: I already tried `var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID"+index)` this but not working.. I'll try again may be I made mistake.. i'll let you know

Comment: It should work, but it returns a list. Also it returns the DOM elements themselves. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with single quoutes and double quotes :

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName("ACID"+index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there can be more than one element with same name, so we need to get first element with that name, I have corrected your query check this, it will work.

```
var acidCount = document.getElementsByName('ACID'+index)[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using wildcard `*` in the selector which will return all matched elements

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id*=ACID]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are naming your elements `'ACID' + index`, you can utilize the `querySelector` method as follows:

```
for (var i=0; i < arracid.length; i++) {
    var $el = document.querySelector('#ACID' + i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using class name.

```
 $(document).find(".tblrows").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
 });
```